# Javascript Array Startswith Exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, startswith

I am again stuck in an exercise that I show you below. I think i might got the correct answer, however it keeps on saying the same error. Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much

Using this characters array, print to the console every character which name begins with ‘M’. Don’t use any kind of loop, yet. We’ll get to that in a second.

And this is what I have, that I supposed it is correct, however, it keeps saying the same error:

```js
var filmCharacters = [
  ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
  ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
  ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
  ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
];

for (var i = 0; i < filmCharacters.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < filmCharacters[i].length; j++) {
    if (filmCharacters[i][j].startsWith('M')) {
      console.log(filmCharacters[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

```
Output
```

> > > > Code is incorrect
> > > > Make sure not to miss any names and print each one separately.
> > > > Michael
> > > > Mia
> > > > M
> > > > Moneypenny

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong here, maybe try to put `\n` at the end of `console.log()` like this `console.log(filmCharacters[i][j] + '\n');` or extra comma like this `console.log(filmCharacters[i][j] + ',');`

Comment: Don't they suggest you not use any kind of loop yet?

Comment: indeed, now that I see it you're right. What would you recommend then?

Comment: Maybe they just want you to index them with hard coded indices. Did they teach you array class methods like `join()` or `filter()`? If not I highly doubt they want you to use them.

Comment: this is an admisson exam and they already 'teached' us the join() one, but I don't recall learning filer()

Answer (score 0):

Well... it expects you to print all the elements in one line with space seprated.

Try this..

```
filmCharacters.flatMap(a=>a.filter(b=>b.startsWith('M'))).join(" ")
```

Much better than using nested loops.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, the same error continues to appear.

Comment: The solution above should work fine and return the desired output. Not sure what is expected as the correct answer to your exercise. Interested to know their solution.

Comment: me neither and I still couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Should not make any difference, but does this give same error?

```
let fc = filmCharacters.flatMap(a=>a.filter(x => (x.indexOf('M') == 0)));
```

Comment: it still isn't working :(